# Uninstall phpunit from pear

Tags: phpunit, pear

On MAC OS when I use phpunit it says:

```
PHPUnit 4.0.17 by Sebastian Bergmann.

You have installed PHPUnit via PEAR. This installation method is no longer
supported and http://pear.phpunit.de/ will be shut down no later than
December, 31 2014.

Please read http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html and
learn how to use PHPUnit from a PHAR or install it via Composer.
```

So I would like to uninstall it and reinstall the new version 4.1. But when I run:

```
# pear uninstall pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

or

```
# pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
```

it returns:

```
unknown channel ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you uninstalled PEAR afterwards or that the PEAR registry files got overwritten somehow?

If you do the following you should see the phpunit pear channel listed, along with other channels you have registered or installed from:

```
$ pear list-channels
```

For each one you should see the channel domain name, its alias and a summary.

Uninstalling from any of these channels should work in the same way you've been attempting, which is why I think the channel registration files may have been changed somehow.